# Codeigniter Permission denied images upload

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am learning how to upload an image with codeigniter, and i got an error permission denied when i click on the upload without any image, it works well if i select an image. i just hoped it will show my message it is: Please upload an Images,can you have a look on my code and help me figure down my problem.
the error says:
[image]
This is my view code:

```
<head>
<title>CI upload images</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id="gallery">
    <?php if(isset($images) && count($images)): 
    foreach ($images as $image): ?>
    <div class="thumb">
        <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $image['thumb_url']; ?>"/>
        </a>
    </div>

    ?>
    <?php endforeach; else: ?>
        <div id="blank_gallery">Please upload an Images</div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<div id="upload">
    <?php 
    echo form_open_multipart('gallery');
    echo form_upload('userfile');
    echo form_submit('upload', 'Upload');
    echo form_close();
    ?>
</div>
</body>
```

and this is my controller code:

```
class Gallery extends CI_Controller{
function index(){

    $this->load->model('Gallery_model');
    if($this->input->post('upload')){
        $this->Gallery_model->do_upload();
    }

    $data['images'] = $this->Gallery_model->get_images();
    $this->load->view('gallery_view', $data);

}
}
```

and here is my model

```
class Gallery_model extends CI_Model{

var $gallery_path;
var $gallery_path_url;

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

    $this->gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../images');
    $this->gallery_path_url = base_url().'images/';
}
function do_upload(){
    $config = array(
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
        'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path,
        'max_size' => 2000
        );
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->do_upload();
    $image_data = $this->upload->data();

    $config = array(
        'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],
        'new_image' => $this->gallery_path . '/thumbs',
        'maintain_ration' => true,
        'width' => 150,
        'height' => 100
        );
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
}
function get_images(){
    $files = scandir($this->gallery_path);
    $files = array_diff($files, array('.','..','thumbs'));

    $images = array();

    foreach ($files as $files) {
        $images []= array(
            'url'=> $this->gallery_path_url . $files,
            'thumb_url' => $this->gallery_path_url . 'thumbs/' . $files
            );
    }
    return $images;
}
}
```

can you please help?

Comment: give permission to your folder where you storing images. In linux : command is : sudo chmod -R 777 [your folder name]

Comment: You forget to define the path where image will be upload

`$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';`

Comment: @Monty how can i give permission on windows 10?

Comment: @AhmedKhan where should i define that? on the model yeah?

Comment: in windows there is no need to give permission. but you can check just in folder properties and check read and write

Answer (score 1):

```
  'new_image' => $this->gallery_path . '/thumbs',
```

Sets the destination image name/path. You'll use this preference when creating an image copy. **The path must be a relative or absolute server path, not a URL.**

you set new_image as folder, not filename. make it like $this->gallery_path . '/thumbs/my_new_file.ext'

Comment: Does that folder exists?

Comment: yes, the problem here is just when i click upload but i did not select the image yet, if it has an image, everything work well

Comment: @HoàngTrungHiếu Correct. it is not the problem of permission. User has not selected the file and clicking on the upload button so he needs to put the server side validation while uploading the file.

Comment: @AlankarMore but how can i display a message that says: please choose an image not that kind of error?

Comment: You can put javascript validation. You can use jquery.validation.min.js for the same. but make sure you can have server side validations too. I have shown that in my below answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do u hv terminal access ? Go to the root of you project folder and type the following in your terminal `sudo chmod -R 755 *` or `sudo chmod -R 777 *` 
The first option has issues in some some projects hence the second option.

Answer (score 0):

Do not upload the image directly without checking the errors. Before uploading check there any errors in file. Change your function as below:

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->model('Gallery_model');
    if ($this->input->post('upload')) {
        $errors = $this->Gallery_model->do_upload();
        if (!$errors) {
            $data['images'] = $this->Gallery_model->get_images();
            $this->load->view('gallery_view', $data);
        } else {
            // your error displaying page.
        }
    }
}

function do_upload()
{
    $error = array();
    $config = array(
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
        'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path,
        'max_size' => 2000
    );
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    } else {
        $this->upload->do_upload();
        $image_data = $this->upload->data();

        $config = array(
            'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],
            'new_image' => $this->gallery_path . '/thumbs',
            'maintain_ration' => true,
            'width' => 150,
            'height' => 100
        );
        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
    }

    return $error;
}
```

For more information read [HERE](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Answer (score 0):

First Validate the image upload or not, then resize the image

```
$result = array();

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {

        $result['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();


    }else {

       $image_data = $this->upload->data();

     $result['image_data']      =   $image_data;    

        $config = array(
        'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],
        'new_image' => $this->gallery_path . '/thumbs',
        'maintain_ration' => true,
        'width' => 150,
        'height' => 100
        );

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();

    }

return $result;
```